# Intersection of a line through two points on a unit circle with real axis

Tags: complex-numbers, circles, analytic-geometry

Suppose we are given two points on unit circle which are represented as complex numbers $u$, $v$. We want to show that the intersection of the line through $u$ and $v$ and the real axis is
$$z=\frac{u+v}{1+uv}.$$
(Again, the complex number $z$ represents the point in plane.)

I will show below my derivation of this formula. I would like to ask:

- Are there simpler/other ways to get to the same result?

---

If I draw the picture, then I see, that I want to find a point which lies on the line going through $a=\frac{u+v}2$ (=center of the line segment joining $u$ and $v$) which is perpendicular to the vector from the origin the point $a$.

If $a$ is the point with coordinates $(R\cos\alpha,R\sin\alpha)$, then I get that $z=\frac{R}{\cos\alpha}$ (simply from the right-angle triangle fromed by $0$, $a$ and $z$). Since $R=|a|$ and $R\cos\alpha=\frac{a+\overline{a}}2$, I get that
$$z=\frac{|a|^2}{\frac{a+\overline{a}}2} = \frac{2a\overline{a}}{a+\overline a}.$$

By plugging $a=\frac{u+v}2$ and using $\overline u = \frac1u$ and $\overline v=\frac 1v$ (since they are on unit circle), I get

$$z = \frac{2a\overline{a}}{a+\overline a} = \frac{\frac{(u+v)(\overline{u}+\overline{v})}2}{\frac{u+\overline{u}+v+\overline{v}}2} =
\frac{(u+v)(\overline{u}+\overline{v})}{u+\overline{u}+v+\overline{v}} = \frac{(u+v)(\frac1u+\frac1v)}{u+\frac1u+v+\frac1v} = 
\frac{\frac{(u+v)^2}{uv}}{u+\frac1u+v+\frac1v} = \frac{(u+v)^2}{u^2v+v+uv^2+u} = \frac{(u+v)^2}{(u+v)(uv+1)} = \frac{u+v}{uv+1}.$$

---

This is the same question as in another post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162656/the-x-intercept-of-a-straight-line-through-points-on-the-unit-circle). The post was put on-hold. Since it seems interesting to me, I would like to repost a better version of that question. Hopefully, I have added enough so that this is not closed for lack of context/effort.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how complex numbers play a role here. I am just using the first point as $u(\cos\theta_1,\sin\theta_1)$ and the second as $v(\cos\theta_2,\sin\theta_2)$, write down the equation of the line (this assumes that we don't have $\theta_1=\theta_2$ or $\theta_1=-\theta_2$ --- in the first case there is no line and in the second the answer is $\cos(\theta_1)=\cos(\theta_2)$ - draw a picture).

If $\theta_2+\theta_1\neq\pi$ I find the intersection at

$$\frac{\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)}{\sin(\theta_1)-\sin(\theta_2)}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a quick check whether this leads to the same formula: $\frac{\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)}{\sin\theta_1-\sin\theta_2}=
\frac{\frac uv - \frac vu}{u-\frac1u -v+\frac1v} = \frac{u^2-v^2}{u^2v-v-uv^2+u} = \frac{(u-v)(u+v)}{(u-v)(uv+1)} = \frac{u+v}{uv+1}$

Comment: To answer the first sentence of your post: *I don't see how complex numbers play a role here.* Well, the original problem (see the link in my post) was formulated as the task to find the intersection when the points are given as complex numbers. I was somehow surprised that it is such a simple formula, so I wondered whether there is an easy way to the same result. (To be honest, formula in your post is also simpler that I would expect the result of this.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I appreciate what you are saying but a line in the complex plane is geometrically the same object as a line in the $x$-$y$ plane. I mean you could embed your problem in quaternionic space but you would never actually use any properties of the quaternions. The same principle applies here. By the way, can you see how I got my answer?

Comment: Re: *Can you see how I got my answer?* Probably there are many ways to get to this formula. For example by putting
$\dfrac{x-\cos\theta_2}{-\sin\theta_2}
=\dfrac{\cos\theta_1-\cos\theta_2}{\sin\theta_1 - \sin\theta_2}$ we get
$x=\cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_2\cdot \dfrac{\cos\theta_1-\cos\theta_2}{\sin\theta_1 - \sin\theta_2} =$ 
$\dfrac{\cos\theta_2(\sin\theta_1 - \sin\theta_2)-\sin\theta_2(\cos\theta_1 - \cos\theta_2)}{\sin\theta_1-\sin\theta_2}=$ 
$\dfrac{\cos\theta_2\sin\theta_1 - \sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1}{\sin\theta_1-\sin\theta_2}=
\dfrac{\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)}{\sin\theta_1-\sin\theta_2}$

Comment: Yeah... I just find find the line $y=mx+c$ and solve for $x$ when $y=0$... what you have here.